# perl get nested functions and parameters (text::balanced or plain perl)

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I have a text file with the following content and would like to extract nested functions (including rootfunc) in an array or other data structure with perl.

INPUT FILE CONTENT:

```
rootfunc aaa with string1 {
    blah blah
    subfunc bbb (different parameters) {
        blah blah
    }
    subfunc others_in_aaa (different parameters) {
        blah blah
    }
}

rootfunc ccc with string2 {
    blah blah
    if (blah) {
        blah blah
    } else {
        blah blah
    }
    subfunc others_in_ccc (different parameters) {
        blah blah
    }
}

rootfunc others with stringothers {
    blah blah
    subfunc others_in_others (different parameters) {
        blah blah
    }
}
```

I would like to extract all the rootfunc and subfunc with the output like below:

INTENDED OUTPUT FILE (not, the if/else are also stripped out):

```
rootfunc aaa with string1 {
    subfunc bbb (different parameters) {
    }
    subfunc others_in_aaa (different parameters) {
    }
}

rootfunc ccc with string2 {
    subfunc others_in_ccc (different parameters) {
    }
}

rootfunc others with stringothers {
    subfunc others_in_others (different parameters) {
    }
}
```

With the perl script as follow I can only extract whatever is in the bracket of rootfunc and then get whatever is in subfunc, but the rootfunc name/parameters and subfunc name/parameters are lost:

PERL SCRIPT:

```
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_multiple extract_bracketed);

open(FILE, "/tmp/a") || die "Unable to open /tmp/a: $!\n";
{
    local $/=undef;
    my $file = <FILE>;
}
close(FILE);
my @array = extract_multiple($file, [sub{extract_bracketed($_[0], '{}')},], undef, 1);
```

Is there any method to get the desired output? Thanks,

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that you want the content of all second-level braces removed?

Comment: @Borodin Some blah to be removed is also at level one.

Comment: I want the first level content(name) as well... Just some blahs to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `subfunc` is a keyword, you can use a  regular expression. I've split it into two s///, but it can be combined.

```
sub squeeze {
    my( $s ) = @_;
    $s =~ s/(?<=\{\n)[^(){}]*?(?= *subfunc)//sg;
    $s =~ s/(?<=\{)[^(){}]*?(?=\})//sg;
    return $s;
}
```

If there are nested braces then Text::Balanced can be used in combination with regexes:

```
sub squeeze {
    my( $s ) = @_;
    my $out = '';
    while( $s =~ s/^(\s*rootfunc[^{]*\{).*?(?=\s*subfunc)//s ){
        $out .= $1 ;
        while( $s =~ s/^(\s*subfunc[^)]+\)\s*).*?(?=\{)//s ){
            $out .= $1;
            my( $ext, $rem ) = extract_bracketed( $s, '{' );
            $out .= "{}";
            $s = $rem;
        }
        $out .= "}";
        if( $s =~ s/^(\s+\})//s ){
            $s .= $1;
        }
    } 
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the regexs you posted work quite well in most cases. But it stopped working when there is {} inside of "blah blah". I've modified the question to include {}

Comment: Then, I suppose, braces may also occur inside `subfunc...(){ here: {} ...}`?

Comment: your solution is brilliant! I made minor changes and accepted it! Happy Easter! :)

Comment: @JieLi Thanks for adding the additional `}` - somehow I lost that in the last round.